# Notepad++ - How to search files for a missing string

Tags: regex, search, notepad++, missing-data

I have cluster of 10 folders, each with 1000 program files.  I need to search these text files for a string.  All files must start with $O123456.MIN% (123456 bearing random file names).  I know how to find if the string exists, but how do I identify if the string does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?!(\$O[^\s]+\.MIN%)).*
```

It matches every string except of the form a `$` followed by a `O` followed by `1 or more characters except whitespace` followed by a `.` followed by `MIN%`

Comment: This is close, but it returns all rows in the file (1000+). And if ran againsts 1000 files, it seems to hang. The string I want to identify if it is NOT there, is always the first line.